# Wireguard PPA for 18.04 LTS

Tags: software-installation, vpn, ppa, wireguard

Is the Wireguard PPA on launchpad for 18.04 defunct now (October 7th, 2020)?  If so, has it been moved or just deprecated.

Comment: 18.04 HWE now uses kernel 5.4, which has Wireguard baked in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Info from [https://launchpad.net/~wireguard](https://launchpad.net/%7Ewireguard)** : This formerly was responsible for producing a PPA for WireGuard on Ubuntu. That functionality has now been folded into Ubuntu itself, so our old PPA has been removed. Simply run `apt install wireguard` on all Ubuntus ≥ 16.04.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.